# Sequence of vectors spaces of linear transformations of vector spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory

Let $V_0$ be a vector space over some field k. Then the set of linear transformations $V_1 = \{T:V_0\rightarrow V_0\mid T\text{ is linear}\}$ is a vector space.

Now, let $V_{n+1}= \{T:V_n\rightarrow V_n\mid T\text{ is linear}\}$. Does this sequence have any interesting properties? Is there a limiting vector space? For a finite dimensional $V_0$, I suspect that the limit will be a space with countably infinite dimension since $\dim V_n=(\dim V_0)^{2^n}$.

In general, in a closed category, does the sequence defined by $x_{n+1} = \text{Hom}(x_n,x_n)$ (where Hom is the internal Hom of *C*) for some $x_0$ have a limit or have some interesting properties? Is there a more algebraic definition for the limit if it exists?

Comment: How do you define a limit without a topology?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is trying to throw a tensor product in here somewhere. Is there a chance we could represent Hom$(V,V)$ in terms of a quotient of the tensor $V\otimes_k V$?

Comment: @copper.hat why, by defining a topology of course!

Comment: @Frank: If $V,W$ are vector spaces, then $V^* \otimes W \to \hom(V,W), \phi \otimes w \mapsto (v \mapsto \phi(v)w)$ is an embedding, the image consists of those linear maps of finite rank. Thus if $W$ or $V$ is finite-dimensional, we have a canonical isomorphism $V^* \otimes W \cong \hom(V,W)$.

Comment: @fhyve: You will get answers as soon as you make your question more precise. What do you mean by a limit? Since you work in closed categories, you seem to have in mind some limit (or colimit) in the sense of category theory? But what are the transition maps? There are no canonical maps between $V$ and $\mathrm{End}(V)$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I'm afraid I can't really do that. I just saw that the vector space of transformations was also a vector space so I wondered what would happen if you take set of transformations on that space, and then do it again a whole bunch. Invoking "limit," especially in the analytical sense, was probably a bad idea. Wondering if looking at it as repeated application of the functor $f:C\rightarrow C$ with $v \mapsto \hom (v,v)$ help formalize it, or perhaps some way to define it inductively.

Comment: What would the infinite (co)product of the whole sequence look like?

Comment: @Martin Thanks for that.  So we have canonical isomorphisms $V_0^*\otimes V_0\cong \hom(V_0,V_0)=V_1$, and $V_2\cong V_1^*\otimes V_1=(V_0^*\otimes V_0)^*\otimes (V_0^*\otimes V_0)$ ... though I don't know how 'dual' works in the case of tensor products.

Comment: @Frank: There is a canonical map $V^* \otimes W^* \to (V \otimes W)^*$, and again it is an isomorphism when $V$ or $W$ are finite-dimensional. All thus stuff (more generally for finitely generated projective modules) can be found in Bourbaki's *Algèbre*.

Comment: @fhyve: You are familiar from analysis that you can ask for every sequence (say with values in a metric space) whatsoever if it has a limit or not. But this is not the case in category theory. You have to specify a *diagram*, which can be imagined as a sequence together with transition maps. These transition maps are crucial! For example, the colimit of $\mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{1} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{1} \dotsc$ is $\mathbb{Z}$, but the colimit of $\mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{2} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{2} \dotsc$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$. Your question doesn't make sense without these maps.

Comment: @fhyve: Ok you could say, let's take no transition maps at all, so that the (co)limit is equal to the (co)product. But here the result is not interesting at all. It's just a huge direct sum/product consisting of random vector spaces with no relation between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've already explained in the comments (and this here is again another comment, but too long), in order to get some interesting colimit, we need nontrivial transition maps $V_n \to V_{n+1}$. I don't see one for $n=0$, but there is one for $n>0$, and the colimit doesn't depend on the first step. So let's start with $V_1=\mathrm{End}_k(V)$, or more generally, let's start with any $k$-algebra $A$. Define $A_1 := A$ and $A_{n+1}:=\mathrm{End}_k(A_n)$ (endomorphisms as a vector space), this is again a $k$-algebra. Then the multiplication $A \otimes A \to A$ corresponds to a linear map $A \to \mathrm{End}_k(A)$, namely $a \mapsto (b \mapsto ab)$. This is even an injective homomorphism of $k$-algebras. For $A$ replaced by $A_n$ we get a transition map $A_n \hookrightarrow A_{n+1}$. We can consider the colimit $A_{\infty} = \mathrm{colim}_n ~ A_n$, which is a $k$-algebra. In most cases it is of infinite dimension. We have $k_{\infty}=k$, but I don't have any nice description $M_2(k)_{\infty}$. Note that that $A_n$ as well as the transition maps for $n>1$, thus also $A_{\infty}$, only depend on the vector space structure of $A$. So somehow this construction is quite strange. It is also not functorial with respect to homomorphisms, only with respect to isomorphisms.